# How can I change the date of 12h to 24h?

Tags: 14.04, server, date

How can I change the date of 12h to 24h of my ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS?

My current locale:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
```

Using `$ sudo date nnddhhmmyyyy.ss`?

Comment: What is your current locale?

Comment: $ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"

Comment: `$ sudo date nnddhhmmyyyy.ss` ?

Comment: normally I would say yes to that. But it could be overwritten the 1st time it does a synch.

Comment: do you have any idea to do that?